# AWS Greengrass - Cant connect core to greengrass. Error in daemon 1. syntax error. Unexpected &

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli, aws-iot

I'm trying to install AWS Greengrass core software in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, using [this tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/gg-setup.html).

when I tried to start the connection using

```
sudo ./greengrassd start
```

following error shows

> /greengrass/ggc/packages/1.1.0/bin/daemon: 1: /greengrass/ggc/packages/1.1.0/bin/daemon: Syntax error: "&" unexpected

[image: see image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means you can't run it on your hardware, I've faced with that when I wanted to install GG on Raspberry PI zero. 
Before installing Greengrass core, consider which hardware you are using. You can find the minimum hardware requirements and compatible hardware architecture for Greengrass [here](https://aws.amazon.com/greengrass/faqs/?nc1=h_ls). Also you can find your hardware architecture type using `uname -m`. If you have compatible hardware then go on with this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/gg-gs.html), 
and download Greengrass software which is compatible with your hardware architecture.
After installation, it's recommended to run greengrass dependency checker, you can find it [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-greengrass-samples/tree/master/greengrass-dependency-checker-GGCv1.5.0).

Answer (score 2):

There's not a lot of information to go on, but: `Syntax error: "$THING" unexpected` is typically output by the shell when it tries to run a program as a shellscript after the kernel has given up trying to launch it as a binary, even though it had binary magic. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336436) for more info.

That, in turn, is often the result of trying to launch a program that is a compiled binary for a different architecture or operating system than the one you are running.

In this case, I would bet that this is your problem. Since the greengrass stuff can be downloaded for multiple architectures, make sure you have downloaded the correct `.tar.gz` for your platform's architecture. [This step](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/gg-config.html) in the greengrass tutorial has the download step in the final subsection--make sure that you have selected the correct architecture in the highlighted box in the lower left:

[image: Image from AWS Greengrass tutorial]

To determine your architecture, use the `arch` command, or `uname -m`. If the two disagree, prefer the latter in most cases. For more information on how to determine your system's architecture, see the answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12453).

This is also mentioned in the official help docs: it is the first troubleshooting step mentioned in the "The AWS Greengrass core software does not start successfully" category of the [official greengrass troubleshooting guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/gg-troubleshooting.html).